# sendAsynchronousRequest says that it finds nil when unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, swift, sendasynchronousrequest

This is the part of my code that crashes:

```
let bodyData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password

let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "URL OF A PHP FILE")!
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) // Crashes here !
{
    (response, data, error) in

    var output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    [Rest of the code]
}
```

the error is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I thinks it's NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest that makes my app crashes cause i've debugged my app and it crashes there

This is the value of request:

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x14d55b70> { URL: [URL OF PHP FILE] }
```

And i know that the data variable is not nil

Comment: My guess would be a badly formed URL string. Check if `request` is nil or not.

Comment: The value of request is: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x15dc4c70> { URL: [URL to php file] }

Comment: Why are you sending an asynchronous operation to the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`sendAsynchronousRequest` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:), the `response`, `data`, and `error` variables in the callback are all implicitly unwrapped optionals. If any of them is nil, a fatal error will be thrown at runtime.

To fix this, define them as normal optionals in the callback block and unwrap them as usual using optional binding or value checking.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
    (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think the document is wrong since data and error simply cannot be non-nil at the same time, otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The documentation is correct in that it describes the behavior of the function. This seems more like a flaw in the design of the Swift API for `NSURLConnection` when it was ported from Objective-C.

Comment: Right. In the document it's said `handler: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)`, which should be `handler: (NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void)`, and literally the document is right. I think part of the document is exported and it correctly reflects the `Swift` implementation, and the implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The request is working fine, but I suspect the response is not because of invalid formatted `"URL OF A PHP FILE"`. The code that process this `data` is the one crashing.

I can generate the same error (I tested the code on AppDelegate) when `data` is nil and invalid URL by encoding `data`

```
let dataStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

If there is safety check beforehand, it is not crashing though:

```
if let notNilData = data {
    let dataStr = NSString(data: notNilData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} else {
    print("nil data")
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is crashing before printing "nil data" and i did a curl with all the post parameters i need and it return all the data that i need so i don't think that the data is nil

Comment: Then, I am out of idea here. Sorry. The second suspect I have is threading issue. Maybe you can try to execute that code block somewhere else.